# Running intellij project inside of WSL Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, intellij-idea

I've installed Windows subsystem for Linux and I'm trying to run a simple python project.

However, I get the following error in the **run dialog** of intellij.

> zsh:cd:1: no such file or directory: \wsl$Ubuntu-18.04homeuserrepotest_project

Not sure why the location above is missing the slashes as it's inside the project stucture. It does however pick up the **Project SDK** as `3.6 @ Ubuntu 18.04 Python 3.6.9`

Also worth noting, I created the project using the intellij wizard setting the location to `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\home\user\code\test_project`

Comment: ``\`` is an escape character. Try using `\\\\wsl$\\Ubuntu-18.04\\home\\user\\code\\test_project`

Comment: It says invalid location when trying to create a new project using double slashes. Also can't change an existing project to that, as you need to browse to it; not able to type the path manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it configuring a path mapping:

File -> Settings -> Languages & Framework -> Ruby SDK and Gems -> Folder Icon

Local Path: `//wsl$/Ubuntu-18.04/home/user/code/test_project`

Remote Path: `/home/user/code/test_project`